# javascript callback not working

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this

```
function SocialMiner()     
{
    var verbose=true;
    var profileArray=new Array();
    var tabUrl;
    this.getTabUrl=function(callback)
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
        {
            myUrl = tab.url;
            console.log("0"+tab.url);
            console.log("calling callback");
            callback.call(tab.url);

        });
    }    

    this.setTabUrlValue=function(pageUrl)
    {
        console.log("1"+pageUrl);
        tabUrl=pageUrl;
    }
};
```

I call the first method with second as callback

```
 var pageUrl=miner.getTabUrl(miner.setTabUrlValue);
```

What I observe is that , second function does not receives the value, i.e. pageUrl is undefined, however it was correctly passed in first function. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax to [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) is incorrect; the first parameter to `call` is what determines the value of `this` inside of the function you're calling. The second argument is where you would place an array of arguments to pass to the function

You could simply use

```
callback(tab.url);
```

in this case.

If you wanted to use `call`:

```
callback.call(this, tab.url);
```

Comment: @ninjagecko do you mean callback.call and not just callback() ?

Comment: @Matt oops yes, sorry that was a typo >_> deleted, for the record the corrected comment should have been: *"or in general you can do `callback.call(this, tab.url)` if, for some reason, you wished to replace the the `this` object"*